# Is there a built in way to crunch an image in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need a smaller version of an image saved to my server alongside the original size of the image saved.

Is there a default Laravel image crunching facility or a plugin that works with the original `->move` function that anyone knows of?

Comment: Nope, Laravel doesn't have a default image facility AFAIK

Comment: Thanks man, very helpful... I'll leave open for a while to see if anyone else can help :)

Comment: I have given it a shot below. I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, no, Laravel doesn't have a built-in image facility. But there are others:

1. Intervention Image is an open source PHP image handling and manipulation library. http://image.intervention.io/
2. Image Cow is PHP library to manipulate and generate responsive images https://github.com/oscarotero/imageCow

Intervention Image looks good. It also has a good Laravel integration. For example, the code below shows how easy it is to resize your image.

```
// usage inside a laravel route
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $img = Image::make('foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);

    return $img->response('jpg');
});
```

Comment: How do I save this to the server using Laravel? Considering the Iamge type is not supported by the ->move() ?

Comment: You can use the `save()` method provided by Intervention [here](http://image.intervention.io/api/save)